# What is the glide ratio of a DA42?

Tags: engine-failure, glide-ratio

I was looking for the best glide speed of a DA42 with both engines out, but it seems it's not in the POH. In the emergency checklist, it only mentions a speed of 85 knots to maintain on final approach with landing flaps.

Comment: In case no information can be derived from the usual sources, (as the POH) the best glide speed can be obtained by finding the maximum endurance speed (the speed that gives the minimum variometer reading when gliding with the engines at idle) and multiplying it by 1,32

Comment: @xxavier, where did you get the number 1.32? The ratio between best gliding range and best gliding time speeds depends on the lift/drag ratio.

Comment: @Jan Hudec  The ratio of 1,32 (more precisely, the fourth root of 3) is the quotient maximum range speed/maximum endurance speed. Hence, if you determine experimentally the maximum endurance speed by watching the variometer while gliding with the engines idling, you can derive the maximum glide speed just by multiplying the maximum endurance speed by 1,32...

Comment: @Jan Hudec  I forgot giving the references. A derivation can be found here http://web.mit.edu/16.unified/www/FALL/thermodynamics/notes/node99.html   And another one here  https://cafe.foundation/v2/pdf_tech/MPG.engines/AIAA.1980.1847.B.H.Carson.pdf

Comment: @xxavier, that only applies to *powered* best range and endurance speed and only valid for piston-powered propeller aircraft. Best gliding time speed is the same as best endurance, but best gliding range speed is different from best powered range speed.

Comment: @ The ratio is valid for any airplane. Read the references, and you'll see that the power used may be of any type, piston-powered, jet-powered, or 'gravitationally powered', as in a glider. For any type or size of airplane, the ratio [speed for max. range] / [speed for max. endurance] is 1,32...  Thus, a pilot may determine the speed for max. range by gliding and observing at what speed the variometer gives a minimum value, and multiplying that speed by 1,32     The min. variometer corresponds, in a glide to the least 'rate of consumption' of pot. grav. energy, i.e. the least power required...

Comment: @Jan Hudec  Besides, please note that the OP asks about the 'best glide speed with both engines out'. Obviously, in that condition the plane is gliding, and when gliding the only power available is that derived from 'potential energy consumption', i.e. loss of altitude. And the rate of loss of altitude is measured with the variometer, so the minimum reading of the variometer corresponds to the speed for minimum power, i.e. the speed for maximum endurance... You take that speed, multiply it by 1,316... and presto! you get the speed for maximum range...

Comment: @xxavier, You take that speed, multiply it by 1,316 and you get the speed for maximum range *powered*. Maximum range *gliding* is *different*.

Comment: @Jan Hudec Different...? Explain why...